# How can I make the images zoom in on click and display the image, and more details like the specific image price and dimensions?

Tags: android

I have 29 images with their small illustrations in a single activity, which I want to make them zoom, and also display more descriptions after clicking. this is in a bid to avoid getting each image a specific activity.

This is an app that is intended to display images of products and their respective descriptions and prices, which will also calculate the total price after amount of units are input.

Comment: Can you show us what you already tried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with RecylerView + CardView (Custome View with LargeImage), on CardView Click handle the event (Open ImageView in Dialog). also defile dialog in large size as image is much more clear and visible to user.

Comment: Oo! Thats Great. If there is any other help from my side please let me know & appreciate the answer.